# How to write xsd for a complex element

Tags: xml

I have a xml like this

```
<jobs>
     <job job_type="full time">
       <title department="distribution">Manager</title>
       <description>Managing the distribution</description>
       <location>Delhi</location>
       <salary>100,000</salary>
     </job>
```

I wrote xsd for this as below

```
<xs:scema>
   <xs:element name="jobs">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="job">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:attribute name="job_type"  type="xs:string/>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title">
                 <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:attribute name="department"  type="xs:string/>
                 </xs:complexType>     
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:integer"/>
         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
```

Can i know whether this is write or wrong ? and what is the correct way to write a complex element which is having a attribute and also other sub elements.

Comment: Right or wrong in what sense? Please [edit] your post so we know what you're asking. As a start, it looks like a quote is missing on a couple of the `attribute` entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the results of converting your xml example to xsd at the [XSD/XML Schema Generator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output) webpage. In order to convert xml to xsd.

1. Paste the XML data in the XML data box.
2. Click the *Generate XSD* button.

```
<xs:schema>  
  <xs:element name="jobs">  
    <xs:complexType>  
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name="job">  
          <xs:complexType>  
            <xs:sequence>  
              <xs:element name="title">  
                <xs:complexType>  
                  <xs:simpleContent>  
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">  
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="department"/>  
                    </xs:extension>  
                  </xs:simpleContent>  
                </xs:complexType>  
              </xs:element>  
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="description"/>  
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="location"/>  
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="salary"/>  
            </xs:sequence>  
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="job_type"/>  
          </xs:complexType>  
        </xs:element>  
      </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:complexType>  
  </xs:element>  
</xs:schema>
```

#### Notes

1. A well-formed XML input file should have a closing tag for the `<jobs>` tag, so a new line should be added to the end of your input XML file as follows: `</jobs>`
2. Note that "description", "location" and "salary" appear before "job type" in the schema and "salary" type is converted to "xs:string".
3. If you want the "salary" type to be shown as integer, change the input `<salary>100,000</salary>` to `<salary>100000</salary>` by removing the comma in the number `100,000`. This changes the "salary" type line in the schema as follows:

   ```
   <xs:element type="xs:int" name="salary"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer :-)